# C# Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq

How to find Min,Max,Sum of given array?

```
int[] number = { 1, 2, 3, 78, 100, 1001 };
```

**(not working)**

```
var query = new { maximum = number.Max, 
minimum = number.Min, Sum = number.Sum };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
var values = new { 
               maximum = number.Max(), 
               minimum = number.Min(), 
               Sum = number.Sum() 
            };
```

Note that those are 3 separate calls, like if it were linq2sql, those would cause 3 separate roundtrips. To pull it off in a single roundtrip, you could have a query that gives a single element in the `from x in y where somecondition select` ...

Answer (score 1):

those are functions, so

```
number.Max()

number.Min()

number.Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Max, Min, and Sum are methods, not properties of the number array. So, you have to call them as you would a method (with parentheses).

```
var query = new { maximum = number.Max(), minimum = number.Min(), Sum = number.Sum() };
```